# window.location to download file with large request data

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

We are using window.location() to download files from server. We are sending a JSON string along with request. As this being a GET request, I am forced to have restriction on the length of the JSON string. How can I send more data with window.location? sort of POST request to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to download a file using POST method..?

One method is to create a hidden form with post method and submit it using javascript. Then the server has to respond back with a `content-disposition` header to download the file.

If you can't add this header, then you have to send a post request using ajax and then save the response you get back using version client-side technics like: [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) or [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)